# How can I set data-slide-to, same as I set id for each .carousel-indicators li

Tags: javascript

How can I set data-slide-to, same as I set id for each li#myCarousel

**HTML**

I have set ids 0, 1 ...

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="" id="0"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="" id="1"></li>  
</ol>
```

**JS**

```
  var iD = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-indicators li');
  // Set their ID
  for (var i = 0; i < iD.length; i++) 
  iD[i].id = + i;
```

I need set also data-slide-to 0, 1 ...

**JS**

```
var dataslideto = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-indicators li');
// Set their data-slide-to
for (var i = 0; i < dataslideto.length; i++)
dataslideto[i].data-slide-to = + i;
```

**HTML OUTPUT I NEED**

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" id="0"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" id="1"></li> 
</ol>
```

*** JOB done i have replace js to ***

```
var i = 0;
$(".carousel-indicators li").each( function() {
$(this).attr("data-slide-to", +i);
$(this).attr("id", +i);
i++;
});
```

Comment: you didn't mentioned class attribute in li

or it should be in <UI> .like  class="abc"

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but how i  can set their data-slide-to start from 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: Have made by self: var i = 0;
$(".carousel-indicators li").each( function() {

$(this).attr("data-slide-to", +i);
$(this).attr("id", +i);
i++;

});

Comment: that is jQuery @Edijs , you did not include the JavaScript tag in your question. My JavaScript answer does exactly the same, but without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You set the ID based on the index of the `for` loop, at the same time you can also set the data attribute:

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-indicators li');
  for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++) {
  abcElements[i].id = + i;
  abcElements[i].setAttribute('data-slide-to', i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also this can be solution.

Comment: I'm glad you got the answer to your question. Feel free to mark this at the correct answer @Edijs